# Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : non-finite location and/or size for viewport: SOLUTION

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2

There are a slew of posts about this littered around SO & the web in general, with few solutions other than [updating packages](https://github.com/oswaldosantos/ggsn/issues/21) or [sorting factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855545/how-can-i-solve-non-finite-location-and-or-size-for-viewport-error), neither of which solve/apply to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

What I found to be the cause & solution of the error was `if` statements within `ggplot`, e.g.:

```
ggplot() +
  if ("SlopeSea" %in% overlays) annotation_spatial(SlopeSea, col = "black") +
```

Fails but:

```
ggplot() +
  {if ("SlopeSea" %in% overlays) annotation_spatial(SlopeSea, col = "black")} +
```

Succeeds, i.e. you have to put the whole `if` line, except the `+`, in {curly brackets}.
Hopefully this helps someone else. Probably future me.