# ggplot not working, error Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use ggplot regularly. I was rerunning some scripts tonight and for the first time am getting this error on every plot.

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_setviewport, vp, TRUE) :
> non-finite location and/or size for viewport

after checking my DFs nothing seemed wrong.  I even ran a super basic line:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = 1, y = 1))
```

and still get the same error.

can someone help?!  perhaps it is a conflicting package or something?  I am running ggplot version 3.3.2.

thank you!

Comment: Try this: `Session` menu -> `Restart R`. Otherwise see here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855545/how-can-i-solve-non-finite-location-and-or-size-for-viewport-error>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RStudio? This happens sometimes to me when the Plots pane is too small to display the graph. Try enlarging it by dragging the sides and see if you're still getting the error?